# Getting Memory Usage in percentage (%) in C#

Tags: performance, memory, memory-management, cpu-usage, performancecounter

I want to get the Memory Usage of a particular process in percentage (%). Below is the code which I used for CPU. But I am unable to get the same for Memory. There are so many counters in Memory Performance that I'm confused how to calculate or we can directly get the display in percentage (%).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 0;
    try
    {
        PerformanceCounterCategory cpuProcessCategory = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Process");
        string[] instanceNames = cpuProcessCategory.GetInstanceNames();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        foreach (string name in instanceNames)
        {
            try
            {
                PerformanceCounter cpuProcess = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", name);
                PerformanceCounter memProcess = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available KBytes");

                cpuProcess.NextValue();
                //Thread.Sleep(5000);
                float cpuUsage = cpuProcess.NextValue();
                float memUsage = memProcess.NextValue();
                //Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                //Console.Write("Process:'{0}'   CPU Usage: {1}%   RAM Free: {2}KB", name, cpuUsage, memUsage);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write("Process: '{0}'   ", name);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.Write("CPU Usage: {0}%   ", cpuUsage);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.Write("RAM Free: {0}KB", memUsage);
                Console.WriteLine("");

                i++;                        
            }

            catch
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot read CPU Usage for process: {0}", name);
            }
        }


    }
    catch
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot retrieve Performance Counter statistics");
    }

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("Total no. of processes: " + i);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: An "amount of free RAM" statistic is completely meaningless on a demand paged virtual memory operating system.  If the operating system cannot find a way to use available RAM then you bought too much of it.

Answer (score 1):

Performance counters is not good idea.
Use this code instead:

```
var wmiObject = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_OperatingSystem");

var memoryValues = wmiObject.Get().Cast < ManagementObject > ().Select(mo = > new {
    FreePhysicalMemory = Double.Parse(mo["FreePhysicalMemory"].ToString()),
    TotalVisibleMemorySize = Double.Parse(mo["TotalVisibleMemorySize"].ToString())
}).FirstOrDefault();

if (memoryValues != null) {
    var percent = ((memoryValues.TotalVisibleMemorySize - memoryValues.FreePhysicalMemory) / memoryValues.TotalVisibleMemorySize) * 100;
}
```